# Print returns of two conditions in the same function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Why do I print only the return of the first condition and not the second? I want to print them both. How can I print the return of the first and second condition at the same time?

I would get output "yes1" e "no2", and **i would use individually them and recall them.**

```
def a():
    
   if 2 > 1:
       print("yes 1")
       variable_1 = yes1
       return variable_1
   else:
       variable_2 = no1
       print("no 1")       
       return variable_2


   if 3 < 2:
       variable_3 = yes2
       print("yes 2")
       return variable_3
   else:
       variable_4 = no2
       print("no 2")       
       return variable_4

a()
```

Comment: `return` also acts as an indicator that the function is now over, so it does not execute anything after a `return` statement

Comment: @Anshumaan Mishra I understand. So how can I print 2 different returns of two different conditions but in the same function? Thank you

Comment: since you do not have to assign the result to any variable or, you don't want the function to return anything, just remove the `return` statements.

Comment: @Anshumaan Mishra  I was wrong in writing. I changed the code. Actually I have to assign the result to a variable, because I would like to use the if or else variable in subsequent staves of the same function. How can I solve? Thanks and sorry

Comment: If you want to *return multiple values from a function,* put the values that you want to return into a list and return the list at the end of the function.

Comment: @Jas_99 check out my solution if it works for you...

Comment: @Lancelot du Lac I know, for this very reason I was asking for help and posted the question. Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: @Lancelot du Lac If I had been able to write more reproducible code, then I would have given myself the answer without posting the question. The code is simple and the logic of what I ask is easily understood. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dictionary to save the values of each variables and use it further.

```
def a():
   result = {}  
   if 2 > 1:
       print("yes 1")
       result['variable_1'] = 'yes1'
   else:
       print("no 1")
       result['variable_2'] = 'no1'

   if 3 < 2:
       print("yes 2")
       result['variable_3'] = 'yes2'
   else:
       print("no 2")
       result['variable_4'] = 'no2' 

   return result

result = a()
```

If `yes1 yes2 no1 no2` are just strings

```
def a():
    result = {}  
    if 2 > 1:
       print("yes 1")
       result['variable_1'] = 'yes1'
    else:
       print("no 1")
       result['variable_2'] = 'no1'
    if 3 < 2:
       print("yes 2")
       result['variable_3'] = 'yes2'
    else:
       print("no 2")
       result['variable_4'] = 'no2'
    return result

result = a()
```

And then if you need value of variable_1 you can do so by:

```
print (result['variable_1'])
```

And so on....

Comment: I am trying your code, but there is a syntax error. Which?

Comment: @Jas_99 what's the error?

Comment: Try the exact code which I have shared with you. If you see any errors, please let me know what's that exact error

Comment: @Vaibhav Problem is the pink line appears after the word "return result"

Comment: Now try it. There was one space indentation. Try now.

Comment: @Jas_99 try the edited solution. There was one space indentation which was causing problem.

Comment: @Vaibhav Now I get: result ['variable_1'] = yes1
NameError: name 'yes1' is not defined

Comment: @Jas_99 i thought yes1, yes2, no1, no2 are declared variables. If they are string check the updated solution

Comment: @Jas_99 try the 2nd part of solution if yes1 yes2 no1 no2 are just strings.

Comment: @Jas_99 does this work for you?

Comment: @Jas_99 can you mark it as answer if this is what you were looking for?

Answer (score -1):

You can certainly return multiple things, but you have to gather them up and return them in one statement.

```
def a():
   togo = []    
   if 2 > 1:
       print("yes 1")
       variable_1 = yes1
       togo.append('yes1')
   else:
       variable_2 = no1
       print("no 1")       
       togo.append('no1')

   if 3 < 2:
       variable_3 = yes2
       print("yes 2")
       togo.append('yes2')
   else:
       variable_4 = no2
       print("no 2")       
       togo.append('no2')

   return togo

print(a())
```

Comment: If I use the list, can I call variable_1 and variable_4 "individually"? Or is togo only used to print them and not to use them? For example if, after return togo, I write if variable_1: print ("ok var1") and then again if variable_4: print ("ok var4"), then "ok var1" and "ok var4" will be printed without problems?

Comment: You can only return values from a function. Once a function ends the names of variables are lost.

Comment: @Tim Roberts I am trying your code, but there is a syntax error. Which? Another question: how can I call variable_1? Should you just write variable_1 or something like togo[variable_1] or similar?

Comment: You cannot use the variables once the function has returned.

Comment: I've fixed the syntax.

Comment: @quamrana I need to use the variables (in the same function) after they have been returned. Can't I use variables in the same function either? Can you tell me then how to solve my problem? Thank you

Comment: @Tim Roberts How can I call the variables individually (in the function)? For example, if I wanted to call variable_1?

Comment: You can't access variable names from outside the function. You have two answers here that return the two values you are looking for.